# unable to connect samsung galaxy s3 via usb cable

Tags: usb

I have a Samsung Galaxy s3 and I wish to transfer some audio files from it to my PC, running Windows 8.

When I connect the phone to the computer with the USB cable, the phone beeps and begins charging but displays no USB connection notification. Likewise, the computer doesn't register the connection at all. I have googled the problem but only seem to find partial solutions, which don't fit my situation.

any help?

Comment: "*I have googled the problem but only seem to find partial solutions, which don't fit my situation.*" -- please [edit] and tell us what you found and what didn't work. It would save us from suggesting or seeking clarification for all those non-working methods.

Comment: First, have you tried a different USB cable? There are some that are for charging only. Second, have you installed the necessary drivers from Samsung? Also try another computer. You need to rule out something to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

So there are several things that could be happening.

- Bad cable: it happens, not too often but often enough. Try a different cable if you can.
- Improper drivers: you don't have the necessary drivers installed on your computer. Look here: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads
- Phone is in the wrong mode. When the phone is connected, there may be a notification telling you that it is connected, touch the notification and change the mode from MTP to PTP (or visa verca).

If those aren't it leave a comment with a few more details and I can try to help you out